# How to get access token with new google sign in with play services 8.3?

Tags: android, google-play-services, access-token, google-signin

I'm trying to switch to the new google sign-in introduced in google play services 8.3 because it doesn't require the get accounts permission. However, I'm unable to get the access token after logging in the user.

There is a requestIdToken(String clientServerId) method in GoogleSignInOptions.Builder but when I put the Oauth 2 client Id of the app from google developer console, it doesn't even log in the user.

Am I using the wrong Id for the "client Server Id"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you are using the Client ID of the web client (your oauth server, should be of type "Web application"), not the Android client.

Comment: Thank you! This solved it. Maybe they're calling it id token now but I think it's the same thing. I'm using [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) to verify the user on the backend before logging in.

Comment: @droidster Actually I am unable to get the correct access token, I tried requestIdToken() and the other getServerAuthCode(), plugged into here: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=access_token_here and all of them return Invalid Value, can you verify the token you get is valid not just in your app but from that link? thanks

Comment: Actually the id token is different than access token. My bad. Please check the link in my comment above. You're using the tokenInfo api for access token. Use tokenInfo api for idtoken. https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=users_id_token_here

Comment: @droidster thanks, my token is valid (based off requestIdToken) now. However did you modify your backend? My backend server doesn't like these new tokens. Basically my question is, are you able to use the same token verification method pre google play services 8.3? Or your backend was updated to use what the google docs show for verification for this new Google Sign-In method

Comment: To support the previous versions of the app in the wild, I'll keep the old code to verify access tokens running as well on the server and add new code to verify id tokens.

Answer (score 2):

```
String clientId = <Client ID of type Web Application.apps.googleusercontent.com>
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(clientId)
                .requestEmail()
```

The You have to create a new credential "OAuth client Id" of type Web Application (as @swimmingtomars mentioned)

It also seems important **not** to add any restrictions, i.e Authorized JavaScript origins or Authorized redirect URIs. This tripped me up as when asked customer to provide their client id asking for type Web Application. They didn't create a fresh one and instead reused an existing client Id that was being used by web app.

[image]